# Detecting datatable change event VB

Tags: vb.net, events, datatable, handler

The objective in this question is to create a code block that executes when a datatable has changed content (just the fact that it has changed, not the specific row/column etc). This is VB Winforms NET.

This works:

```
Public Class Form1
    
    Sub testhandler()
        Dim locallyDeclaredDT as new datatable
        AddHandler locallyDeclaredDT.ColumnChanged, New DataColumnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf Column_Changed)
    End Sub
    
    Private Shared Sub Column_Changed(sender As Object, e As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("The table has changed")
    End Sub
    
End Class
```

But I need a datatable that is accessible outside of the sub's scope so I try this, which doesn't work.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim globallyDeclaredDT as new datatable
                
    Sub testhandler()
        AddHandler globallyDeclaredDT.ColumnChanged, New DataColumnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf Column_Changed)
    End Sub
            
    Private Shared Sub Column_Changed(sender As Object, e As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("The table has changed")
    End Sub
            
End Class
```

The problem is caused by the AddHandler line: the ColumnChanged property is underlined and the error is

> 'ColumnChanged' is not an event of 'Object'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you have not pasted your exact code for a couple reasons: 1) the vb.net capitalization is not correct, so I guess you typed it in your question and 2) I pasted your Form1 code and it works perfectly fine. Somehow your globallyDeclaredDT is an object. I guess a couple things a) you don't have `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file (put it there) and b) you are actually declaring the globallyDeclaredDT as `Dim globallyDeclaredDT = New DataTable` which would make it an Object, not DataTable and then the error message would make sense.